# Build a .XAP File withtou uses Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-7

I work in ah company that wants build a Framework to create windows phone apps. I was choose to study what we need to do this.
Anyway... 
Is there some way to developer for Windows Phone without use Visual Studio?

Comment: I believe a xap is like a zip file, with the extension changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop applications for Windows Phone with the Windows Phone SDK by using either Visual Studio 2010 or Expression Blend 4. You can download the tools (including the SDK) from the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started), which are all available for free.